# What happened when I pass a nested braced-init-lists to constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdinitializerlist

I passed an nested braced-init-lists to class constructor:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

class NestedInteger final {
 public:
  NestedInteger(int i) : type_(INT), val_int_(i) {}

  // NestedInteger(std::initializer_list<NestedInteger> ni) {
  template <typename T>
  NestedInteger(std::initializer_list<T> ni) {
    for (auto it = ni.begin(); it != ni.end(); it++) {
      val_vec_.push_back(*it);
    }   
  }

 private:
  enum { INT, VECTOR } type_;
  int val_int_;
  std::vector<NestedInteger> val_vec_;
};

int main() {
  NestedInteger ni1{1};
  NestedInteger ni2{1, 2, 3}; 
  NestedInteger ni3{{1}, 2, 3}; 
  NestedInteger ni4{{1, 2, 3}};
  NestedInteger ni5{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}};
  return 0;
}
```

And I got compilation error:

```
t.cpp:29:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘NestedInteger::NestedInteger(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   29 |   NestedInteger ni5{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}};
      |                                            ^
t.cpp:12:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> NestedInteger::NestedInteger(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)’
   12 |   NestedInteger(std::initializer_list<T> ni) {
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.cpp:12:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
t.cpp:29:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
   29 |   NestedInteger ni5{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}};
...
```

I read the list initialization in cppreference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). And I can tell the expression belongs to the first syntax type:

> `T object { arg1, arg2, ... };    (1)`
>
> initialization of a named variable with a braced-init-list (that is, a possibly empty brace-enclosed list of expressions or nested braced-init-lists)

I can't understand the [explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) about the effects.

Could you help to figure out:

1. Which item in the [explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) does this case match?
2. <del>Is this a non-deduced contexts described [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.type#5)?</del>

By the way, if I change the template to specific type as the commented line, the compilation error disapeared.

Comment: What should `T` be deduced for `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}`?

Comment: @songyuanyao I guess the parameters in the brace can not be deduced, so the compiler follow the explanation and maybe reaches the phase: "all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed"

Comment: Yes, `T` can't be deduced here. It might be `std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>`, or `std::initializer_list<std::list<int>, std::list<int>>`, and so on.